# Ladders on Servers

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was on a LAN world with my sis, and we were building an automatic ladder. It was powered by a series of commnd blocks with this command:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:ladder
```

It worked, kind of. When it spawned, the ladder stood for a second, but then broke into items.
We were confused, but when I did some testing in a singleplayer world, the command worked just fine! So what gives? Is there a special command we need to be using in servers? Is it a lag problem, or what?

Comment: When I was testing on the singleplayer world, I didn't specify the direction, and it worked just fine! Besides, when I did the command on LAN, the ladder immediately spawned correctly, it just then breaks. How do I provent it from breaking?

Comment: Maybe? But direction's not the issue. This isn't my first command block. If I needed to change directions, I would have done that, but that's not the problem! How to make them stay on a server?

Comment: Singleplayer is essentially like running your own private server and then joining it, so usually there should be no differences. Are you sure you're doing the exact same thing in both worlds? Ladders need a support block. You can place them with commands without support, but they will break as soon as you place a block above/below/next to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I.... uh... actually realized there was a specification issue. When we tested in the singleplayer world, it was facing north. when we tested it in LAN, it was supposed to be facing east. We got our numbers wrong.... Boy do I feel stupid...

Answer (score 1):

As Fabian said, singleplayer is like your own server. When more than one person is loading in chunks in a server, it reload blocks. As the ladder is seen by the code not having a block, it breaks the ladder. Try a chain command that has a **fill** replacing air water and lava behind it to a barrier.